# Unable to access Realm database in app group folder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I am unable to access data stored in my realm database after moving it into an app group container in order to use with a watch kit extension. I tried following this [Guide](https://realm.io/news/tutorial-sharing-data-between-watchkit-and-your-app/), I can successfully print the path to the default Realm after moving it into the app group file, but If I try to print out the amount of objects in the realm it returns 0, which causes my Table to be empty. I have app groups enabled in both my ios, and watch targets with the correct app group name. Heres where I set the default realm folder inside the app delegate.

```
    let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.io.github.brady131313.Deck-of-Death")!
    let realmPath = directory.path!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm")
    Realm.defaultPath = realmPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had set the default realm path after let realm = Realm(), so it was defaulting to the old path instead of the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the directory returned by `NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.io.github.brady131313.Deck-of-Death")` points to a path containing `Containers/Shared/AppGroup`. It will happily return a path within your normal container if you've made a typo in the App Group ID or don't have the necessary entitlements / provisioning profile set up. You should see the same path returned within both your extension and your parent application.

You may want to review Realm's sample WatchKit app for a working example of using Realm with App Groups. You can find it in the Xcode project at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/objc.

Comment: File Manager Group: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/53156B62-D7AE-4FB8-AEF6-A1B92577B9C7/
App Realm: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/53156B62-D7AE-4FB8-AEF6-A1B92577B9C7/db.realm This is what I get for printing out the realm path and the directory, which is the same output for the extension and the app, but I still cant read from the directory.

Comment: Can you try something simple such as writing a regular old plist file to that directory, and seeing if you can read it from your WatchKit extension?

Comment: I'm able to use NSUserDefaults init with suiteName to read a value I set in the main app from the watch extension.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` accesses data via an intermediate daemon (cfprefsd). It's not really analogous to reading / writing files directly. I'd suggest something like `-[NSDictionary writeToURL:atomically:]` / `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:]` with a path inside your App Group's container. If you can share data that way, then your problem is somehow specific to Realm. If not, it's something in your project configuration, or with how you're constructing the URLs.

Answer (score -1):

You set realmPath as directory.path but it isn`t. Change the realmPath difinition.

Comment: What do you mean I set realmPath as directory.path but it isn't?

Comment: I`m not a pro in this subject but maybe you have not properly configured access to your data in realm (some user rights, or delegation rights). Try simple test the access not in app group container but simple as it is.